# UTF-8 misencoding, finding out the way it was misencoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, mojibake

First of all, i searched the forum and the web and found some more or less related threads but not really pointing to my question.

i know that the strings im working with are malformed and i found two sites pointing to what happend (double utf combined with iso-8859-1 somehow)

```
http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html
https://gist.github.com/ImpactSeo/78561612047efa7591264b8276357a4b
```

reversing is relativly easy with these lists, but im trying to understand how to get to these bad strings

what i did so far

i know malformed Ã„ stands for Ä, so i started with an Ä

Ä utf8 encoded is `\xc3\x84` as string
when encoding this using utf8 the second time i get

```
\xc3\x83\xc2\x84
```

quite near to the "desired" output, but the malformed string on the other hand looks like

```
Ã„ is \xc3\x83\xe2\x80\x9e encoded in utf-8
```

can anyone give me a hint or tell me how to get there? i tried different ways combinung utf-8 with iso-8859-1 but no output  matches

Comment: `'Ä'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` - common windows encodings are always worth a try

Comment: thx for the fast reply, tried iso-8859-1/15 but not windows, (wood and trees), got the desired output now